# Why cant I access $_POST variable with a hyphen/dash in its key if passing key as variable?

Tags: php, arrays, post, array-key

I've written a small static method for my class which returns either `$_POST` variable if it is set or `NULL` otherwise. Input elements in HTML form have names with hyphens for example 'customer-name'.

So I think I could access them like this `$var = $_POST['customer-name']`. But with my method:

```
public static function getPost($param) {
    echo $param." = ".$_POST[$param]."<br/>";
    return isset($_POST[$param]) ? $_POST[$param] : NULL;
}
```

I can not. And I notice some strange behavior when added some `echo` statements to my method. It cuts off everything after a hyphen, so I got error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: customer- in .. on line ..
```

This is how I test it:

```
$arr = (array)$object;
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    $newKey = str_replace(get_class($object), "", $key);
    $newArr[$newKey] = MyObject::getPost(strtolower(get_class($object))."-".$newKey);
}
```

And this is the output from my test:

```
...
Notice: Undefined index: customer- in .. on line 116
customer-id =

Notice: Undefined index: customer- in .. on line 116
customer-name =

Notice: Undefined index: customer- in .. on line 116
customer-phonecode =
...
```

**EDIT 1 - I was asked for HTML form**:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <input type="text" name="customer-name" id="customer-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
   <select id="customer-phonecode" name="customer-phonecode" class="form-control">
      <option value="+123"></option>
   </select>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2 - Tested on [phptester.net](http://phptester.net/) on 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5 php versions. Getting same error.**

**EDIT 3 - Tested following script. If passing string as key I get element in super global $_POST/an array. But if passing a variable which points to a string, an element cannot be accessed**

```
<?php
$test = array('customer-test1' => 1, 'customer-test2' => 2);
function getPost($param) {
    global $test;
    $newParam = (string)$param;
    echo $param." = ".$test[$newParam]."<br/>";
    return isset($test[$newParam]) ? $test[$newParam] : NULL;
}
class Customer {
    private $test1;
    private $test2;     
    function __construct() { }
}
$object = new Customer();
$arr = (array)$object;
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    $newKey = str_replace(get_class($object), "", $key);
    $newArr[$newKey] = getPost(strtolower(get_class($object))."-".$newKey);
}
```

Might this be a PHP bug?

Comment: post your HTML form that goes with this. I can't make out why it's failing here.

Comment: What are you doing by this, echo $param." = ".$_POST[$param]."<br/>";

Comment: What is value of $param in getPost($param) {

Comment: @LearningMode I posted it. See test output section please.

Comment: This part `$arr = (array)$object;` I honestly don't get. Shouldn't that read as `$arr = array($object);`? Kind of baffled here lol edit: scratch that. You're doing a scalar.

Comment: I cast object to an array, to be able to get all class members. Check [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-object-vars.php#47075)

Comment: Oh I think I know... `name="customer-name"` etc. needs to be treated as an array `name="customer-name[]"` *most likely*. Same for `name="customer-phonecode"` => `name="customer-phonecode[]"` *missing brackets*.

Comment: No, it didnt help. Im not sure but isnt brackets for multiple inputs with same name? Its not the case here.

Comment: well I thought that you were trying to treat those as arrays. *Obviously not then*. Well, I am baffled. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. I hope someone picks up on the question. Good luck @ksno

Comment: Well I think the problem is not the hyphen here, but the fact that your $newKey being null, and hence the undefined index error as the key doesn't exist..

Comment: @Vincent im not sure but `$newKey` is being echoed.. Its a part of `$param` argument in my method and its being echoed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was, that casting object to an array adds null characters to array keys. They are not just class name+property name. It's how PHP manages private class properties when casting.

```
$object = new Customer();
$arr = (array)$object;
print_r(array_map("addslashes", array_keys($arr)));
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => \0Customer\0test1 
        [1] => \0Customer\0test2
      )
```

Im not sure why `var_dump()` doesnt show those null bytes. Might be my next question I guess. So those nulls were still there in my static method argument. But why PHP stops right after dash/hyphen?

> In PHP we can simply write:

```
$Tmp= 'hehe';
```

> But for the same in C, we would use the following code:

```
Char Tmp [4];
Tmp [0] = 'h';
Tmp [1] = 'e';
Tmp [2] = 'h';
Tmp [3] = 'e';
Tmp [4] = '\0';
```

> C handles strings as a character array, it needs a way to define the
>   last character of the string. This is done using a null byte. A null
>   byte is donated by \0 in C. So when the program runs, it starts
>   reading the string from the first character until the null byte is
>   reached. This creates a problem. As we know, PHP is also implemented
>   in C. This can become an issue, because some functions in PHP might
>   handle an input string as they are handled by C.

Sources: [#71673](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71673), [null-byte-injection-php](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/null-byte-injection-php/)

**EDIT 1: Solution added**

Solution is to replace '\0' characters as well as class name with `""` in my foreach loop:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
    $newKey = str_replace(array(get_class($object), "\0"), "", $key);
    $newArr[$newKey] = getPost(strtolower(get_class($object))."-".$newKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a limitation of PHP - when using superglobals such as $_POST, there are some "magical" things going on. PHP converts the names of form elements in many ways, for example

```
<input type="text" name="hello[mate]" />
```

Will be accessible as $_POST['hello']['mate'], because the form names are processed as variables. Using dashes is therefore generally not a good idea, because they are not allowed in variable names and probably interfere here. I would advise to only use characters which are allowed for variables in PHP, and replace dashes with underscores.

Comment: I am able to access `$_POST` variables if im passing a string directly like `$_POST['string-with-dash-aka-hyphen']` but not being able to access it when passing variable as key which contains a string like `'string-with-dash-aka-hyphen'`

Comment: It is possible that PHP actually parses variable keys of superglobals in a different way, although I never heard of that. Generally though you are trying to use a character which should rather not be used in form names, so even if you solve this problem, you are bound to have more problems with dashes in the future.

Comment: for not just passing by the question +1, thanks for trying to help.